# Turtlebot teleop fuerte

Tags: turtlebot, ros-fuerte, teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to operate the turtlebot from the keyboard in ROS fuerte?  I had been able to do this without a problem in ROS electric using these instructions: http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_teleop/Tutorials/Teleoperation

When I upgraded to fuerte I no longer have a turtlebot_teleop package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40438/turtlebot-teleop-fuerte/) by [Brad](https://answers.ros.org/users/2761/brad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Fuerte *turtlebot_teleop* is a part of the stack *turtlebot_apps*.

---

Originally posted by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) with karma: 1821 on 2012-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-03**:
and can be easlily found with `roslocate info turtlebot_teleop`.

**Comment by [Brad](https://answers.ros.org/users/2761/brad/) on 2012-08-03**:
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the time being, you can install the [brown-remotelab](http://www.ros.org/wiki/brown_remotelab) stack on your turtlebot, which contains the [teleop_twist_keyboard](http://www.ros.org/wiki/teleop_twist_keyboard) package

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-brown-remotelab
```

As far as I can see running

```
rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py
```

instead of

```
roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch
```

should do the trick. Follow the instructions on-screen to control your turtlebot.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-08-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1